# White noise from ACF Test

Tags: time-series

This is the ACF result for the daily return for spot gold. Is it white noise? or I can do ARIMA model for it.

[image]

Comment: 1) What is the blue area?  2) A priori, we'd expect spot gold to be a pretty efficient market, so there should be a pretty low day-to-day carryover of adjustments to new information (one could imagine some carryover if new information was dropped shortly before "midnight" - the market is essentially a 24-hour one - but otherwise, probably not.)  Consequently, looking at longer lags is almost certainly looking at noise.

Comment: 1) The blue area is the significance threshold I don't remember how to calculate it but It is related to white noise distribution. 2) This is the daily return (gains and losses by pips) to make the data stationary. I agree with you but I think the analysis shows the opposite.